# How can I find the domain and the range of a function?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

I'm working on a task which has the following question:

> What is the *domain* and the *range* to the function *g*?

Here is the function *g*:

> Let *A* - $\{$1, 2, 3, 4$\}$, *B* - $\{$a, b, c, d$\}$
>
> - Let *g* : *B* $\rightarrow$ A be defined so that *g* - $\{$$\lt$a,
>     1$\gt$,$\lt$b, 2$\gt$, $\lt$c, 4$\gt$, $\lt$d, 4$\gt$$\}$

Since the question is asking for the domain to the function *g* and since *B* is the domain to the function *g* and *A* is the codomain to the function g, would the answer; B - {a, b, c, d} is the domain, hold as a correct answer? Or would I have to add something more to it?

Also how can I find the range of the function g?

Would appreciate some help, thanks alot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The domain here is $B=\{a,b,c,d\}$ as it's the set of elements which you *feed in* to the function. The range of $g$ is the set of elements *hit* by $g$ which is a subset of the codomain (which in this example is $A$), and so the range of $g$ is $\{1,2,4\}$ because there does not exist any element $x$ in $B$ such that $g(x)=3$.

In your notation, the last sentence would read "because there does not exist any element $x$ in $B$ such that $\langle x,3\rangle \in g$".